# Counting images on a constantly updating page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to count images on constantly updating page via Jquery in the Google Chrome console,

I've written the next script but it doesn't seem to work properly and i will be glad if you could help me:

```
var count = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
  $('.image .big').each(function(i, obj) {
    if ($('.box').find('img').attr("src") == "special-src/img.png") {
      count++
    } else {
      count--
    };
    $('.image .big').addClass('.done').removeClass('.image .big'); // To not count it multiple times
    console.log(count);
  });
}, 1000);
```

Edit:
The HTML I'm working with looks like that:
(divs are contantly being removed and add)

```
<div class="box">
        <img src="special-src/img.png" class="image big"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
        <img src="special-src/img2.png" class="image big"/>
</div>
```

Comment: It's going to be impossible for anyone to help you here without seeing the HTML you're working with

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , i see , I've edited the question can you tell me if its ok now?

Comment: So to clarify, you're looking to count all the `img` elements with `src="special-src/img.png"` in an interval, and to count each image only once. Is that right?

Comment: Right only img.png and not img2.png

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but its not a count of amount , but a count of balance , so if there is 1 img.png (+1) and 1 img2.png (-1) the count will be 0

Comment: Ah, right well that changes the logic completely. It would probably be better if you edit the question to explain what you're trying to achieve instead of an XY attempt at the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some creative CSS selectors we can find the elements you want to count. I've added some comments to clarify what each selector does. The answer should output the number `2` as I've added three special images and one normal image.

```js
(function() {
  var 
    count = 0,
    // Selector for finding all items with the class "box" but with the class "done".
    selectorNotProcessed = '.box:not(.done)',
    // Selector for all element with the classes "image" and "big" with a "src" attribute
    // that contains "img1.png" and that have an ancestor with the class "box" but not
    // the class "done"
    selectorSpecialNotDone = `${selectorNotProcessed} .image.big[src*="img1.png"]`,
    // Selector for all element with the classes "image" and "big" with a "src" attribute
    // that DOESN'T contain "img1.png" and that have an ancestor with the class "box" but 
    // not the class "done"    
    selectorNotSpecialNotDone = `${selectorNotProcessed} .image.big:not([src*="img1.png"])`;
  
  setInterval(function() {
    var
      // Get all the non processed special src elements.
      specialElements = document.querySelectorAll(selectorSpecialNotDone),
      // Get all the non processed non-special src elements.
      notSpecialElements = document.querySelectorAll(selectorNotSpecialNotDone);
      
    // Update the count of the number of special src elements vs non-special src elements
    count += (specialElements.length - notSpecialElements.length);
    
    // Add the done class to all the elements with the class "box" that do not yet have the
    // class "done".
    document.querySelectorAll(selectorNotProcessed).forEach(element => element.classList.add('done'));
    
    console.log(count);
  }, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="folder/img1.png" class="image big"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="folder/img2.png" class="image big"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="folder/img1.png" class="image big"/>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="folder/img1.png" class="image big"/>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to be almost what i need , but not exactly because i didn't explain myself properly , what the script should do , is count +1 for img.png and -1 for img2.png , they are in the same folder so there is just /special-src/ (there is no not-special-src)
Edit: actually i see that your script is doing exactly what i need ,  just the images should be in the same location and the only difference is the name

Comment: I've updated the answer. Everything with `img1.png` will increase the balance, all others will decrease the balance.

Comment: The answer is right and seems to be working on here, but when i run it on my console it says "undefined" and the .box class does getting .done add to it

Comment: Weird, it works when I run it from the console on a website. What browser are you using?

Comment: Im using chrome

Comment: Than I have no clue why it doesn't work for you in your console, sorry.

Comment: Does it possible that the site blocks usage of the console?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Is it a public website? If it is, can you post the URL so I can try for myself?

Comment: It seems they've something in place that limits the console. It is preventing certain code from running. I didn't even know that was possible. Anyway, seems like your idea isn't going to work.

Comment: Seems like so , anyway way i think your answer would work here if not the block , so i mark it as answered :)

Comment: Do you think the site is also able to block extensions that will try to affect it?

Comment: No idea, I don't even know how they block it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/6SI0Gd) for working example for counting images dynamically.

```
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {

    console.log("document changed");
    if (totalImages !== $(".image.big").length && !disableRecounting) {
         disableRecounting = true;
         console.log("recount images..", totalImages, $(".image.big").length);
       countImages();
     }
});
```